# Django: urls with common prefix and {% url %} with param in view

Tags: python-3.x, django-views, django-urls, django-1.8

In my `urls.py` i have defined something like this:

```
url(r'file-(?P<fid>\d+)\.html', detail, name='detail'),
url(r'file-(?P<fid>\d+)/history', history, name='history'),
url(r'file-(?P<fid>\d+)/edit', edit, name='edit'),
url(r'file-(?P<fid>\d+)/comments', comments, name='comments'),
url(r'file-(?P<fid>\d+)/delete', delete, name='delete'),
```

and in the view:

```
<a href="{% url 'filer:detail' file.id %}">{{ file.name }}</a>&nbsp;
<a href="{% url 'filer:delete' file.id %}"><img src="{% static 'filer/images/delete.png' %}" alt="delete" /></a>
```

and according to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) I can do something like this:

```
url(r'^file-(?P<fid>\d+)', include(
    url(r'^\.html', detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^/history', history, name='history'),
    url(r'^/edit', edit, name='edit'),
    url(r'^/comments', comments, name='comments'),
    url(r'^/delete', delete, name='delete'),
)),
```

but if I change to this include pattern then I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /files/

Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(2,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(2,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I know why I get this error - there are no params in `url(r'^\.html', detail, name='detail'),` - and my question is: how to use this url patterns with include in views using `{% url %}`?

Django: 1.8.2
Python: 3.4.2